# Does anyone have ideas how to make an assert on a button click using CUIT?

Tags: c#, winforms, testing

I use the CUIT tool to make coded ui tests. But (new to this) I am unsure how to assert a button click. Not necessarily the properties of the button (e.g. color when pressed), but to actually assert what happens next ...

Example. Clicking the "New" button should bring up a set of tabbed document pages.

Example2. Clicking "OK" should make the popup disappear.

Example3. Clicking "Save" should update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **properties** of the expected result. if you click OK you can ask if the popup is exist.

```
Clicking on OK button
Mouse.Click(OK);
```

Check if the popup exist

```
If(Popup.exist) 
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Comment: sounds like it makes sense. I will give it a try and get back to you.